# Efficient way to declare and populate multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

What's the most efficient way to declare and populate a multidimensional array in JavaScript?

I'm currently doing this:

```
ff = Array();
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    ff[i] = Array();
    ff[i][i] = 1.0;
}

ff[1][2] = 0.041666667;
ff[1][3] = 0.000694444;
ff[2][3] = 0.016666667;
ff[1][4] = 0.000011574;
ff[2][4] = 0.000277778;
ff[3][4] = 0.016666667;
ff[1][5] = 0.000011574;
ff[2][5] = 0.000035315;
ff[3][5] = 0.00211888;
ff[4][5] = 0.1271328;
ff[1][6] = 0.000000025;
ff[2][6] = 0.000000589;
ff[3][6] = 0.000035315;
ff[4][6] = 0.00211888;
ff[5][6] = 0.016666667;
```

up to `ff[n][n]` where `n` can be up to 30, which leads to hundreds of lines of declaring array values (does this matter, even when minified?). I only need to populate the "top" half of the array since `ff[n][n] = 1` and `ff[i][j] = 1/(ff[j][i])` so after the declaration I loop over the whole array and invert the "top" half to populate the "bottom" half.

Comment: How are the values generated?

Comment: Don't use `ff = Array();` use literal declaration: `ff = [];`

Comment: Test the alternatives that come up with http://jsperf.com/

Comment: @Chad you are a real life jslint :D

Comment: @howderek I'm going to take that as a compliment :D

Comment: if `ff[i][j] = 1/(ff[j][i])`, why bother declaring the second half and just using 1 divided by the first half?

Comment: @Dancrumb The values are unit conversion factors, so they're static and can be hard-coded.

Comment: @James, understood, but can they be generated programatically?

Comment: @James could you add a link? Or even better a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @user1032531 I only declare the values for the top half of the array - you'll note that ff[1][1], ff[2][2], etc are missing and that for ff[i][j], the maximum value of i is always j-1

Comment: So, it looks like these are time conversion factors; how is your array constructed? Is there a way to determine from numeric index what you're trying to convert. Also, wouldn't an Object be a better fit here?

Comment: @Dancrumb Not really, the values are of a format similar to apples/second to oranges/hour to grapefruits/day. So even taking the per unit time factor out, I'd still need to hard code the apples to oranges to grapefruits values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your numbers, it looks like you're trying to convert between various time units.

I wonder if a better fit wouldn't be an object.

```
var seconds = {
  day:   86400,
  hour:   3600,
  minute:   60,
  second:    1
};

var conversions = {};

['day','minute','hour','second'].forEach(function(fromUnit){
  var subConversions = {};
  var fromValue = seconds[fromUnit];
  ['day','minute','hour','second'].forEach(function(toUnit){
    subConversions[toUnit] = fromValue / seconds[toUnit];
  });
  conversions[fromUnit] = subConversions;
});

function convert(value, from, to){
  return value * conversions[from][to];
}
```

This will give you.

> convert(1, 'day','hour') === 24
>
> convert(1, 'day','second') === 86400
>
> convert(3, 'hour','second') === 10800

Even if things are more complicated than simple time conversion, this approach is probably going to lead to much more understandable code. Once you start giving the elements of a multi-dimensional array special meanings, things can get pretty ugly.

Comment: Many thanks for this - your original comments on my question got me thinking and this is certainly a cleaner way.

Comment: One last point: if these values are relatively static, it may make sense to write a script to generate `conversions` then export that to JSON, then manually insert that JSON into your script to statically define things.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following:  And then I would put the script in a separate file which can be cached.

```
ff=[];
ff[0]=[0.041666667,000694444,016666667,000277778,016666667];
ff[1]=[0.041666667,000694444,016666667,000277778,016666667];
ff[2]=[0.041666667,000694444,016666667,000277778,016666667];
ff[3]=[0.041666667,000694444,016666667,000277778,016666667];
ff[4]=[0.041666667,000694444,016666667,000277778,016666667];
ff[5]=[0.041666667,000694444,016666667,000277778,016666667];
```