# How to fill multidimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I tried to get this to work, but the outer loop stops after second iteration, and everything that's after it does not execute(just like it was the end of the script). I want to fill two dimensional array with any character(here i used 'q' as an example)

```
var A=[[],[]];
for(var i=0;i<12;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<81;j++){
        A[i][j]='q';
    }
}
```

It didn't work, so i put `alert(i+' '+j);` to see if it's even executing, and, as i wrote before, it stops after second iteration of outer loop, and then ignores rest of the script.

All I want is to have this array filled with same character in the given range(12 rows, 81 columns in this specific case), so if there's no hope in this method, i'll be glad to see one that works.

Comment: You're only initializing `A` with 2 items. Always check your console for errors before asking why things aren't working. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` Create an array to assign to `[i]` inside the outer loop.

Comment: A neat looking way is something like 
const A = Array(12).fill(0).map(() => Array(81).fill("q"));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to declare and populate multidimensional array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203495/efficient-way-to-declare-and-populate-multidimensional-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var A=[[], []];`

^ This line declares a two dimensional array of size 1x2. Try this instead:

```
var A = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    A[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 81; j++) {
        A[i][j] = 'q';
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer I forgot `A[i] = [];` on the third line when I reformatted the code to make the stack overflow form validation for multiline code happy :) Nice catch!

Comment: sounds pretty slow, is there a faster way?

Answer (score 9):

> The Array.from() method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance
>   from an array-like or iterable object.

```js
function createAndFillTwoDArray({
  rows,
  columns,
  defaultValue
}){
  return Array.from({ length:rows }, () => (
      Array.from({ length:columns }, ()=> defaultValue)
   ))
}

console.log(createAndFillTwoDArray({rows:3, columns:9, defaultValue: 'q'}))
```

Answer (score 8):

This does the job in one line.

`var A = Array(12).fill(null).map(()=>Array(81).fill('q'))`

This is an array of references and a bad idea as harunurhan commented.

`var A = Array(12).fill(Array(81).fill('q'));`

Comment: In this case, all elements of A will refer to the same array reference, so modifying a A[i][j] will modify also A[0...11][j]

Comment: Explained nicely here https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/4-ways-to-populate-an-array-in-javascript-836952aea79f

Answer (score 3):

Since `fill()` is the most succinct and intuitive, and it works as intended for immutable values, my preference would be an outer `from()` and an inner `fill()`:

```
Array.from({length: 12}, _ => new Array(81).fill('q'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The best approach to fill up 2D array would be like the following

```
let array2D = [], row = 3, col = 3, fillValue = 1
for (let i = 0; i < row; i++){
  let temp = []
  for (let j = 0; j < col; j++){
   temp[j] = fillValue
  }
  array2D.push(temp)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way

Array(10).fill(Array(10).fill(0))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise a new array for `i` each time the first loop runs, and you don't need to set the layout of the array before you create it (Remove the `[], []` inside the declaration of `A`). Try this:

```js
var A = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  A[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 81; j++) {
    A[i][j] = 'q';
  }
}
console.log(A);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { 
    max-height: 100% !important; 
    top: 0; 
}
```