# Js Math.random not random

Tags: javascript, loops, random

I can't generate a multidimensional array and fill it with random values, I tried to use for loops, forEach, and map with Math.random, but all arrays are identical.

```
function mat(a=5,b=5,max=2){
  
  let mt = new Array(a).fill(
    new Array(b).fill(0)
  )
  
  mt.map( (x,xk)=>{ 
    x.map( (y,yk)=>{ 
      mt[xk][yk] = Math.round(
        Math.random()*max
      )
    })
  })
  
  return mt
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(mat()))
```

**output example**

```
[[0,0,2,2,0],
 [0,0,2,2,0],
 [0,0,2,2,0],
 [0,0,2,2,0],
 [0,0,2,2,0]]
```

**why?? does not make sense!**

Comment: because of how fill works. You insert the same array in each index... has to have a dupe.

Comment: You are filling your array with 5 references to one and the same array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992415/how-to-fill-multidimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: thank you! I wasn't seeing as an object